# What does it mean if a guy's appearance is described as looking like he were from the local chess club?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Ie ''he looked like he was from the local chess club, and also dressed the part - not your conventional t-shirt and jeans.''

Comment: In the West, at least, being part of a chess club is considered nerdy, so the writer probably intended something like [this](https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/nerd-young-man-isolated-on-white-picture-id157317395).

Comment: ...but not like [this](https://www.rubiconline.com/review-the-queens-gambit/)...

Answer (score 1):

"From the local chess club" is a literary way of describing someone who is intellectual, introverted, and not overly concerned with (or giving little thought to) their own physical appearance and style.

Their grooming may be below the norm, and their clothing is likely to be chosen for comfort or tradition rather than what is fashionable.

In other words, notably *not* out to impress the ladies :) Or members of the gender of interest :)

As far as "what is fashionable" in this context, the last phrase is telling us that: "T-shirt and jeans".

Comment: I'd quibble with "unconcerned with their appearance" and "dress for comfort". I'd expect a stereotypical member of a chess club to wear dress pants and a dress shirt if male. And he'd probably be male. He wouldn't wear blue jeans and a T-shirt or whatever the latest fashions on. I'd agree with you on "chosen for ... tradition". Yeah, probably not out to impress the ladies because another aspect of the stereotype is that he's shy and introverted (as you mentioned).

Comment: BTW I'm speaking as someone who was president of the science club when I was in high school, so I was the chief geek. :-) I used to be on the steering committee for a technology conference and one year, instead of the usual lanyards, I got everyone pocket protectors to hold their IDs.